# Why is my iteration through records adding whole object dump in a strange place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have two Models, Habit and HabitLog.

For simplicity Habit holds a name and has many HabitLogs.
HabitLog holds a date and status.

I want to create a view for specific date and list all the Habits with status for given date.

To get records, but keep association I used this query in my controller:

#### habit_log_controller.rb

```
def show
  @habit_logs = HabitLog.where(log_date: '2015-07-15').includes(:habit).order("habits.position")
end
```

Then in my view I have

#### show.html.erb

```
<ul>
  <%= @habit_logs.each do |habit_log| %>
    <li>
      <%= habit_log.habit.name + " " + habit_log.status %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It works, meaning in lists all the Habit names and status for given day, but it pastes the whole array in a strange place, after the li tag, but inside ul.

#### Page source

```
<ul>

  <li>
     Waga 87
  </li>

  <li>
     Higiena 1
  </li>

  <li>
     Siłownia 0
  </li>
  [#&lt;HabitLog id: 1, log_date: &quot;2015-07-15&quot;, status: &quot;87&quot;, habit_id: 1, created_at: &quot;2015-07-15 11:37:21&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2015-07-15 11:37:21&quot;&gt;, #&lt;HabitLog id: 2, log_date: &quot;2015-07-15&quot;, status: &quot;1&quot;, habit_id: 2, created_at: &quot;2015-07-15 11:37:28&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2015-07-15 11:37:28&quot;&gt;, #&lt;HabitLog id: 3, log_date: &quot;2015-07-15&quot;, status: &quot;0&quot;, habit_id: 3, created_at: &quot;2015-07-15 11:37:30&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2015-07-15 11:37:30&quot;&gt;]

</ul>
```

I figure this has to do with my use of .includes(:habit), but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: You're writing the output of `each` with `<%=` in `<%= @habit_logs.each do |habit_log| %>`.  Replace with `<% @habit_logs.each do |habit_log| %>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
<%= @habit_logs.each do |habit_log| %>
```

should be

```
<% @habit_logs.each do |habit_log| %>
```

***Imp Note:***

```
<% %> # Executes the code.

<%= %> # Prints the output.
```

Comment: @LittleMary Don't be. After all WE do the mistakes :)